# EF6: FullText Search not working with multiple WHERE

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, full-text-search

So I have setup an DB interceptor as described in this [article](http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch).

**Code that works:**

```
var ft = FtsInterceptor.Fts('something');
var queryable1 = db.Sometable.Where(x=> x.Id > 30);
var queryable2 = db.Sometable.Where(x=> x.Name != null && x.Name.Contains(ft));
var final = (from q1 in queryable1 join q2 in queryable2 on q1.Id equals q2.Id select q1).ToList();
```

**Code that doesn't work:**

```
var ft = FtsInterceptor.Fts('something');
var queryable = db.Sometable.Where(x=> x.Id > 30);
queryable = queryable.Where(x=> x.Name != null && x.Name.Contains(ft));
var final = queryable.ToList();
```

I don't get any errors but the results are completely off. I get no results with multiple `WHERE`where as `JOIN` works as expected.

Comment: Are You sure about content in Sometable.Name? I suppose, It would be better to check If it's NullOrEmpty

Comment: I updated the question, adding `NULL` check condition

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% certain that Sometable.Name always contains data? You might want to make that line read `var queryable2 = db.Sometable.Where(x=> (x.Name ?? "").Contains(ft));` so that there is never a null value.

Comment: I tried adding null check and yes the error went away but I don't get any result with multiple `WHERE`